# Wondering why I must assign to session variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I have to assign to a session variable for it to have the right number in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1, name FROM cities;
```

Instead of something like:

```sql
SELECT @row_number, name FROM cities;
```

In the second form it returns what I'm guessing is the last row number.  Maybe even the value of a `COUNT(*)`.  It's almost as if the value is somehow closed over.  What is going on in these two queries?

Comment: no need to assign to a session variable, what session variable you are assigning?

Comment: If you don't assign to it, it won't add 1 each time.

Comment: @aRvi `@row_number` is the session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign to it in order to add 1 to the value on each row. If you don't do this, you get the same value on every row, which isn't a row number. It will be whatever was left from the last time you assigned the variable, which might be the total number of rows from a previous query that was correctly incrementing.

If you're using MySQL 8.x you can replace this use of session variables with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 1):

you have `@row_number` variable. Everytime the below sql hits the record it shows the result and increments by one.

```
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1, name FROM cities;
```

if you are using mysql 8.0+, you can use `row_number` window function to achieve same result

```
select row_number() over (order by <pk>) rn, name from cities;
```

If we turn back to `SELECT @row_number, name FROM cities;`, you are not icrementing `@row_number` which in turns shows always same value which is assigned value for `@row_number`

PS: please also note that you are not using `order by` clause on your query which may lead to inconsistent row numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of session variable, for MySQL version 8+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and for below MySQL 8 you can do this

```
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1, name 
FROM cities,
(SELECT @row_number:= 0) AS x;
```